# BeautifulSoup returns None when using find method with specific attribute

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to extract information with BeautifulSoup from a webpage that has a `<a>` tag inside a `<span>` tag:

`<span> at txn <a href="/tx/0xc3400990117385ca81de274fc5cca8d7965e92729cfb294035dd7d2e740bf1c5" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="hash-tag text-truncate" data-original-title="Creator Txn Hash">0xc3400990117385ca81de274fc5cca8d7965e92729cfb294035dd7d2e740bf1c5</a></span>`

I want to extract the value **0xc340xc3400990117385ca81de274fc5cca8d7965e92729cfb294035dd7d2e740bf1c5** which is after the data-original-title="Creator Txn Hash" inside the anchor tag.

I am using the find method with attrs specified. My code is:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
adr = soup.find('a', attrs={'data-original-title': 'Creator Txn Hash'})
print(adr.get('value'))
```

This code retuns: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'. If i try to print just the adr like `print(adr)` it returns None

I have also tried with span and also returns None.

```
adr = soup.find('span', attrs={'data-original-title': 'Creator Txn Hash'})
```

What am i doing wrong here? Any help would be much appreciated.

**Question Update:**

I am pasting my complete code. Probably the problem arises when python loads the whole page and not if you olny search in an html portion of the page.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

site= "https://etherscan.io/address/0x92f754bd63719422cce0d82c3bebfdbfba9d6e69"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = Request(site,headers=hdr)
page = urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

adr = soup.find('a', attrs={'data-original-title': 'Creator Txn Hash'})
print(adr.text)
```

Also, is there another way(maybe faster in terms of program execution) to get that address from the page?

Comment: Do you have a typo in the txn hash you're looking for? In your question it's `0xc340xc3400990117385ca81de274fc5cca8d7965e92729cfb294035dd7d2e740bf1c5` but actually is `0xc3400990117385ca81de274fc5cca8d7965e92729cfb294035dd7d2e740bf1c5`. (You've repeated `0xc340` at the start.)

Comment: Yes, that is a typo

Comment: In the updated code, some of the content on the page is loaded dynamically via Javascript. So it's not present in the page source initially. Use [tag:selenium] to load the page in a browser and then look for the transaction details. Look into it and try that. Post another question if you run into issues doing it.

Comment: That was the case. With selenium i solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `adr.get('value')`, use **`adr.text`**:

```py
>>> adr = soup.find('a', attrs={'data-original-title': 'Creator Txn Hash'})
>>> print(adr.text)
0xc3400990117385ca81de274fc5cca8d7965e92729cfb294035dd7d2e740bf1c5
```

Wrt

> If i try to print just the adr like `print(adr)` it returns None

That works fine for me.

---

In the updated code, some of the content on the page is loaded dynamically via Javascript. So it's not present in the page source initially. Use [selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium) to load the page in a browser and then look for the transaction details. Look into it and try that. Post another question if you run into issues doing it.

Comment: With print(adr) I am getting: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Re-check that the code in your post is the actual code. Because _your code_ works fine for me. Btw, `print(adr)` can't give the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'` since it's not looking up the text attribute. It would just print `None` if it was actually None.

Comment: check my question update where i pasted all my code to see if you can reproduce the error